# Rails Devise gem, removing require tree gives css error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, asset-pipeline

I'm using Rails 4 and the devise gem in development.

In my `application.css` when I remove:

`*= require_tree .` (this is because I am trying to have custom css for different controllers)

I lose my devise css information and get an error in the console:

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/devise/sessions.css"):`

Any ideas how I can solve this in the cleanest way possible?

Comment: Devise gem doesn't provide any CSS files. So, seems like `sessions.css` is your file. Check where and how are you using it in your project.

Comment: Thanks @maxd, your comment helped me find my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that devise does not generate views and assets such as stylesheets when installed without configuration. So to solve this issue one needs to run:

`rails generate devise:views`

and then create `sessions.css` under `app/assets/stylesheets/devise/sessions.css` for it to get picked up by Rails and not error on the console.